# WooCommerce — formatting dimensions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use a [Woo Variations Table](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-variations-table/) plugin (seems to be discontinued), that formats variable goods in a nice table. However it has problems displaying product dimensions: it shows

> { "length": "1", "width": "2", "height": "3" }

instead of

> 1 x 2 x 3 cm

Looks like plugin uses 'dimensions', that refers to

```
'dimensions' => $variation->get_dimensions( false ),
```

in class-wc-product-variable.php file.
Changing 'false' to 'true' solves the problem, and the question is:
**how can I get dimensions formatted w/o editting class-wc-product-variable.php core file and adding this construction in plugin .php file or functions theme file?**

Comment: Check this plugin must have any filter using that you can edit in your theme's functions.php file.

Comment: @dipmala didn't understand your comment. The plugin doesn't have any filters in GUI, if you meant that. I could not edit dimensions performance via plugin code, the only thing that helped was editing a string in woocommerce core file (that is, obviously, undesirable).